# DateTime filtering in DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable, dataview, rowfilter

I have tried to filter the DateTime column from a DataTable using RowFilter and the column contains the Date with the Time.

[image]

I have tried like below,

```
dataView.RowFilter = "[Date] = #6/26/2011 2:53:24 PM#";
```

But the filter is not working.

Could anyone please update me the proper filter string to filter the date column in DataTable ?

Comment: _Date values should be enclosed within pound signs (#) or single quotes (') based on the data provider_

Comment: @Steve - I have tried giving pound signs and single quotes also, but the filter is not working properly.

Comment: Try `"Date = #2011/06/26 11:46:43#";`

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_ exactly by the way? Is this filter works on your database engine itself? Are you _really_ sure about the format part?

Comment: Which database engine/provider you are using by the way?

Comment: @SonerGönül -  I am just using DataTable in winforms application.

Comment: @Zer0 -  the provided solution not working.

Comment: @Amal What is your `CurrentCulture` by the way?

Comment: @SonerGönül - Refer this thread for clear understanding about exact case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51042097/filtering-in-datatable-is-not-working-for-datetime-now-or-datetime-adddays

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
  string str =  "YourDateTime";

  string dtFilter = string.Format("[Date] = '{0} '", str);
  (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = dtFilter;
```

Comment: I have updated the question with Data image and the filter text. Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CONVERT(expression, type)` syntax to convert you text to a RowFilter DateTime.

For example:

```cs
dataView.RowFilter = "[Date] = CONVERT('6/26/2011 2:53:24 PM', 'System.DateTime')";
```

Reference: [DataView.RowFilter Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Reference: CONVERT function in [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8#functions)

Answer (score 0):

Dim strFilter As String = "MovDay >= '" & dteInitial.ToShortDateString & "'" & " AND " & "MovDay <= '" & dteFin.ToShortDateString & "'"

```
dSetNewMov.Tables(0).DefaultView.RowFilter = strFilter
```