# Filtering in DataTable is not working for DateTime.Now or DateTime.AddDays

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I am trying to filter the DateTime in DataTable and experiencing a strange filtering issue.

**1) Data and Filtering - Working fine**

```
public DataTable GetDataTable()
{
DataTable employeeCollection = new DataTable();
var dt = DateTime.Now;

employeeCollection.Columns.Add("EmployeeID", typeof(int));
employeeCollection.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Employee ID";
employeeCollection.Columns.Add("EmployeeName", typeof(string));
employeeCollection.Columns["EmployeeName"].ColumnName = "Employee Name";
employeeCollection.Columns.Add("CustomerID", typeof(string));
employeeCollection.Columns["CustomerID"].ColumnName = "Customer ID";
employeeCollection.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
employeeCollection.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 26, 4, 34, 45);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 27, 4, 34, 45);

employeeCollection.Rows.Add(1011, "DintinAmam", "Alfki", "Britain", date1);
employeeCollection.Rows.Add(1012, "JohnAmam", "Johanesberg", "China", date2);

string filterString = "Date = #" + date1.ToString() + "#";

employeeCollection.DefaultView.RowFilter = filterString;

return employeeCollection;
}
```

**Filter string - "Date = #6/26/2011 4:34:45 AM#"**

**Output1:**
[image]

**2) Data and Filtering - Not working**

```
public DataTable GetDataTable()
{
DataTable employeeCollection = new DataTable();
var dt = DateTime.Now;

employeeCollection.Columns.Add("EmployeeID", typeof(int));
employeeCollection.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Employee ID";
employeeCollection.Columns.Add("EmployeeName", typeof(string));
employeeCollection.Columns["EmployeeName"].ColumnName = "Employee Name";
employeeCollection.Columns.Add("CustomerID", typeof(string));
employeeCollection.Columns["CustomerID"].ColumnName = "Customer ID";
employeeCollection.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
employeeCollection.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

employeeCollection.Rows.Add(1011, "DintinAmam", "Alfki", "Britain", date1);
employeeCollection.Rows.Add(1012, "JohnAmam", "Johanesberg", "China", date2);

string filterString = "Date = #" + date1.ToString() + "#";

employeeCollection.DefaultView.RowFilter = filterString;

return employeeCollection;
}
```

**Filter string - "Date = #6/27/2018 5:19:17 PM#"**

**Output2:**

[image]

When creating DateTime value with Constructor, filtering works fine and when using DateTime.Now filtering is not working.

**Could anyone please confirm me, why initializing Date value using DateTime.Now.AddDays() is not working for filtering ?**

Comment: Another option might be to do something like `"Date >= #6/27/2018 5:19:17 PM# AND Date < #6/27/2018 5:19:18 PM#`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row filter for date/time values handles sub second components (milliseconds...).

But the default format for date/time does not include these.

Your filter will only work when `date1` and `date2` don't have sub second components which is the case in your first code snippet (this `DateTime` constructor sets them to 0).

One solution is to give `ToString` a format that does include the sub second components.

Comment: `DateTime.ToShortDateString` is handy to truncate the time portion.